# Add a column with fixed values to a ListView's GridView

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

I bound a ListView to a List(Of List(Of Integer)).
I can specify the columns thus:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ResultsByDenomination}">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="      "/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Noord" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [0]}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Oost" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [1]}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Zuid" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [2]}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="West" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [3]}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

This lays out the ListOfList neatly in a square grid.
However, I want to fill the first column with fixed values.
How do I do that, apart from rebuilding the ListOfListOf Integer to a ListOfList Of string and add the first column with fixed values there?

EDIT: Basically I want to add RowHeaders.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by fixed values? Do you have another list that has the length as the main list?

Comment: @ svick: I know beforehand how many rows there will be. Let's say I just want to prefix the integer rows with 'One','Two', 'Three' and 'Four'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one data structure for the row headers and another one for the row data, simply transform the data into a new data structure that is easily consumable by the `ListView` by combining them.  Since you seem to like "nuts and bolts" data structures, you can use a `List<Tuple<string, List<int>>>` for this.

Here is a simple example.  First the code-behind to simulate your `ResultsByDenomination` property:

```
void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var rowHeaders = new List<string> { "One", "Two" };
    var rowData = new List<List<int>>
    {
        new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        new List<int> { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
    };
    var listViewData = rowHeaders.Zip(rowData, (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b)).ToList();
    DataContext = listViewData;
}
```

and the modified XAML to support the new data structure:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item1}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Noord" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item2[0]}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Oost" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item2[1]}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Zuid" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item2[2]}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="West" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item2[3]}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

You can also create a utility class instead of using `Tuple` with more descriptive names.